# wp-login.php ampersand in url results in 404

Tags: urls, htaccess, 404-error, encoding

I've got this problem where the wordpress site will throw up a 404 if the wp-login.php has an ampersand appended after it (e.g. session expired argument).

I've changed themes, disabled all plugins, renamed .htaccess to .htaccess1 and I still get a 404.

It looks like wp-login.php is not linking the "&" after it e.g "wp-login&whatever=blah".

I also have another problem if the "redirect_to" has a colon in it e.g. "redirect_to=http://blah.com/" it will result in a 404 too. If you remove the colon, you just get the login page.

So I suspect both issues are related and its not encoding the url properly? So it sees theses symbols as programing syntax.

I don't code in php so I need some help on what code and where to put it to ensure when WP loads a page it ensures the url its fed is encode properly...

Any help grately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use [add_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to get login url,

```
$arr_params = array( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'tiny' );
echo add_query_arg( $arr_params ,wp_login_url());
```